# I need to remove the date

Tags: regex, renaming

I need to enter regex into a field which ONLY identifies a varying date.

All files use the same format of: name.y%.m%.d%.blahblahblah

This is an example of what the filename would look like:

LordOfTheRings.14.6.28.The.Twin.Towers

Comment: And, have you tried anything? Do we have to match the date or would finding the first and last `.`s and replacing everything between also solve the problem?

Comment: you may also provide actual samples of strings as well for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a file called `x`.

```
f=open(x,'r')
data=f.read()
import re
y=re.sub(r".\d{2,4}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}."," - ",x)
new=open(y,'w')
new.write(data)
```

After all delete the old file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This is the whole algorithm.Which requirement does it not cover?

Comment: Your answer was flagged as a low quality. In my opinion it's true. I don't understand what I should do to solve the problem. I've to open the file "LordOfTheRings.14.6.28.The.Twin.Towers" then copy python code inside this file? Sorry but this is really a very low quality answer.

Comment: ohh got your point.Corrected now.Actually didnt want to give the whole code ,so gave a sort of algorithm.newaz it was confusing.